# MonogDB C# Driver LINQ query not working when filtering by _id

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am currently trying to build a web API that interfaces with MongoDB using the C# driver.

The GET route uses several optional parameters that dynamically generate the LINQ query based on which parameters are in the request.  The issue I am having is when filtering by _id it always fails to return data; these attempts include _id.ToString() as well as a simple _id == id comparison.  I have tried several methods of comparing the id parameter and the document _id and none of them have worked.  Having no where clause at all, or filtering by any other fields in the document in any combination all return data as expected.

This is currently what the snippet looks like:

```
 var testId = new ObjectId(id);

 var result = collection.AsQueryable<Terrain>()
                 .Where(t => t._id.Equals(testId))
                 .Select(t => t);

  return Json(result);
```

This will return an empty result [].  I can only assume I am misunderstanding something about the way _id is being stored being the database and queried here.  For testing purposes, I am getting the value of the parameter id by copying the _id value out of Robo 3T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_id property needed to be decorated as follows.  Database was storing _id as a string and not ObjectID.

```
namespace RIDBAPI.Models
{
  
    public class Terrain
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("prefab")]
        public string prefab { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("colour")]
        public string colour { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("v3")]
        public decimal[] v3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please share your 'Terrain' model
- Please note that you are initiating an empty testId object and you are trying to match your documents _id to an empty object. You should set the testId with the object identifier which you would like to find (for example: var testId = new ObjectId("12345") )

Comment: testId is being initialized with id which is a parameter being passed in from the API.  When debugging testId is both of the data type and value I expect.

Comment: Posted the model in a separate answer for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the .Select at the end (it's actually projecting the document results and if you would like to have the full document - it's not needed)

In addition, add at the end of the query .First() -or- .FirstOrDefault()

It should look something like:

```
 var result = collection.AsQueryable()
                 .Where(t => t._id == testId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Another approach is just using a simple .Find():

```
 var result = collection
                 .Find<Terrain>(t => t._id == testId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem -- there was something wrong with the decorators for the Id property of the Terrain class that was causing it to be stored as a String instead of as ObjectID, which was causing comparison issues.  Fixing this about the data allowed for the comaprison to work properly.

Thanks for your help!